# Is there a way to move an HTML object if the object is too close to the border of the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Context :** When I hover on the tag image, a box shows up and it shows the artwork infos. My problem is, if the tag is too close to left or right border of the window, it cuts the box and we can't see the infos anymore.

**Actual question :** *Is there a way in CSS or JavaScript to move the box to the right side if it's too big to fit in the screen ?*

[image: https://imgur.com/a/tO5JnZq]

*The image shows the box being cut because it's too close to the left border of the window*

Comment: are you using some tooltip like plugin to display the info of the tag

Comment: get the cursor position when the hover event is fired, if it's less than the width of the div that appears from the side of the screen then amend it's position (+/-) from the cursor position

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no i'm not using any plugins but i think i found a solution, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this recently in jquery, basically you get the screen width and the cursors screen position when firing the tooltip, if it won't fit then move it over until it does:

```
$('.showtooltip').on('click touchend', function (e){
    const screenWidth = $(window).width() / 2;
    const x = e.pageX; //Cursor X position
    const y = e.pageY; //Cursor Y position
    const tooltipDirection = e.pageX < screenWidth ? 10 : -200;// if click is on the right of the screen show tooltip to the left of event(-200px)
    const content = "Here's a tooltip";

    if (content.length > 0)
    {
        //insert a span with your content or whatever here
        $('body').append("<div class='custom-tooltip' style='position:absolute;left:" + (x + tooltipDirection) + "px;top:" + y +"px;background-color:#ffa;border:1px solid #cc9;padding:3px;font-size:13px;-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px #666;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 11px #666;'>" + content + "</div>");


         setTimeout(function(){//remove the span after 3 seconds
             $('.custom-tooltip').fadeOut(function(){
                 $(this).remove();
             });
         },3000);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Use in-line CSS , either margin or padding for space in left side :

```
style="margin:10px" or "padding:10px"
```

for margin or padding in right side :

```
style="position:absolute,right:10px,margin:10px" or "padding:10px"
```

Hope it will work for your purpose.